# Need help finding drivers for HP laptop

Tags: windows-7, laptop, drivers

I just downgraded my HP Pavilion 15-n284ca laptop from Windows 8 to Windows 7 (x64) and am now seeing the following two devices complain of not having the required drivers:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Could someone point me in the right direction for these drivers and explain how they were able to track them down? I've tried Googling the Hardware IDs but have had no success.

Thanks!

**Edit:**

I get the following window when attempting to install the accelerometer driver:

[image]

After the window is closed, the accelerometer driver (shown as "Unknown device") still shows as missing.

Any ideas?

**Update:** the question has now been answered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Solution

In order to get the right drivers you need to identify the devices through their hardware IDs. Each device has more than one ID: the first one is the most specific, and the last one is the most generic.

The most relevant bits are `VEN_XXXX` and `DEV_YYYY`, which are the vendor ID and the device ID, respectively. The IDs are hexadecimal values associated with a manufacturer/device, which you can lookup using [PCI Database](http://www.pcidatabase.com). USB devices use `VID_XXXX` and `PID_YYYY`, which are similar (PID stands for Product ID). A list can be found at [The USB ID Repository](http://usb-ids.gowdy.us/read/UD/).

You want to get the most specific driver whenever possible, because that's going to be the best match for the device. On the other hand, a generic driver could miss certain features, or it might not even work.

### Realtek card reader

Let's start with the first device. The hardware ID is the following:

```
PCI\VEN_10EC&DEV_5229&SUBSYS_216B103C&REV_01
```

The vendor ID is `10EC`, which is associated to [Realtek](http://www.pcidatabase.com/vendor_details.php?id=1697). The device appears to be a [card reader](http://www.pcidatabase.com/search.php?device_search_str=5229&device_search=Search).

For some reason the HP download page doesn't provide a card reader driver when selecting Windows 7; you'll have to [pick Windows 8](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=4063&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&sw_lang=&product=6825783). It doesn't really matter in this case as the driver package is meant to be compatible with XP and later. The `.inf` installation file does include the correct ID:

```
%Rts5229CR%=Rts5229.Inst, PCI\VEN_10EC&DEV_5229&SUBSYS_216B103C
```

### HP 3D DriveGuard

Here's the hardware ID for the second device:

```
ACPI\HPQ6007
```

A quick search returned a [forum thread](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-Systems-and-Software/Driver-for-HP-Probook-430-G1-for-ACPI-HPQ6007-on-Windows-7/td-p/3011991) which suggested it's related to **HP 3D DriveGuard**, a proprietary [active hard-drive protection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_hard-drive_protection):

> HP 3D DriveGuard receives notifications from the integrated accelerometer and protects the hard drive (HDD) by automatically "parking the heads" to reduce the risk of damage if the notebook/laptop is accidentally dropped or is abruptly impacted by another object.
>
> <sub>Source: [HP 3D DriveGuard | HP® Support](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&softwareitem=ob-78211-1)</sub>

This can be confirmed by inspecting the actual driver package. In fact, the installation file contains the following line:

```
%DeviceDesc% = HPAccelerometerDriverInstall.ntamd64, ACPI\HPQ6007
```

The device is indeed an accelerometer. Here's the human-readable description:

```
DeviceDesc = "HP Mobile Data Protection Sensor"
```

You can download it from the [official support page](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=4063&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&sw_lang=&product=6825783). The setup package won't start properly (as of version `6.0.18.1`), and you'll get the following window:

[image: Screenshot 1]

After further analysis through the task manager, it turned out the command line used is the following:

```
"C:\SWSetup\SP66078\setup.exe" "setup.exe" /s /v"/qn REBOOT=REALLYSUPPRESS"
```

The parameters are messed up. They should have been set like this:

```
"C:\SWSetup\SP66078\setup.exe" "/s /v/qn REBOOT=REALLYSUPPRESS"
```

To workaround this issue, just run the `setup.exe` application manually. When you're done the `C:\SWSetup\SP66078` folder can be deleted. As an alternative you can extract the `spXXXXX.exe` software package yourself using [7-Zip](http://7zip.org/).

---

## Additional information

> Some devices require a vendor-supplied driver that is designed specifically for that device or one that is designed to support a family of devices. However, other devices can be driven by a system-supplied driver that supports all the devices of a given [device setup class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541509(v=vs.85).aspx). Windows selects the driver that most closely matches the device. If Windows does not find such a driver, it selects from increasingly more general drivers.
>
> <sub>Source: [Overview of the Driver Selection Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)</sub>

### Hardware IDs

> Windows identifies devices and the setup classes they belong to by using a special set of identifiers. These identifiers are used to match hardware devices with the device drivers that allow them to communicate with Windows.
>
> One or more device IDs are assigned to a device by its manufacturer. One of them, the hardware ID, is very specific - down to the make, model, and even the firmware version of the device. Other device IDs are also assigned, and are more generic, with the IDs possibly being assigned to other devices from the manufacturer that are compatible at some level.
>
> <sub>Source: [Discovering Hardware IDs and Device Setup Classes for your Devices](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733122%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)</sub>

### INF files

> An INF file is a text file that contains all the information that [device installation components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541277(v=vs.85).aspx) used to install a driver. Windows installs drivers using INF files. This information includes the following:
>
> - Driver name and location
> - Driver version information
> - Registry information
>
> <sub>Source: [Overview of INF Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)</sub>

### Further reading

- [How Windows Selects Drivers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff546228%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Hardware ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff546152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [INF Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547402%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for explaining that so clearly. The card reader driver for Windows 8.1 (x64) worked a charm; however, when I tried installing the Windows 8 (x64) accelerometer driver, it comes up with a command line parameters window (see edit to my question for screenshot), before closing. Driver still shows as missing. Any ideas?

Comment: @Austin''Danger''Powers You should have selected Windows 7 for the accelerometer driver, as it's available. In this specific case the actual executable is identical, but your mileage may vary. Either way, extract the content of the `spXXXXX.exe` setup file using [7-Zip](http://7zip.org/). You should get some files/folders; the one that contains the driver is `InstallFiles\Win7`. Try [installing the driver manually](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-install-hardware-or-device-drivers-manually-in-windows-vista/), and then report back.

Comment: Good point. I didn't realize it had Windows 7 drivers for the accelerometer (turned out it was the same installer anyway). Your idea of extracting then browsing to it manually solved it. Thanks.

Comment: @Austin''Danger''Powers That confirms once more the driver is the proper one. While the driver got installed, the software didn't. The setup package is bugged and doesn't start properly, but you can easily get around the issue. See my edited post for further details. While I was at it, I've also refined the whole answer to provide extra information. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: This is easily one of the best answers I've ever received on this site. I really appreciate the detailed, comprehensive explanation as it finally plugs a gap in my knowledge that's been there the entire 6 year's I've worked in IT and allows me to do better than simply Googling related search terms (which often isn't enough to track down obscure drivers). How many people adopt such a methodical approach? I'm going to memorize any details I didn't already know. Pure gold!

Answer (score 1):

It's probably the 3D DriveGuard driver and one other. The HP forum reply to your post there is pretty thorough. http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-Systems-and-Software/Pavilion-15-n284ca-Windows-7-x64-drivers/m-p/4024486

Answer (score 1):

The device seems to be a Realtek PCIE Card Reader, according to [PCI database](http://www.pcidatabase.com). PCI Database gives [this](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=15&PFid=25&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false) as the download page for the drivers for that device.

Answer (score 0):

I use Driver identifier. Look here: http://www.driveridentifier.com/. Download that program and start it. It will scan your laptop for all drivers. It will automatically direct you to driver identifier web site with list of drivers for your machine.

I didn't found it is unsafe application, I had no problems with it.
Hope it helps you.

---

Tested on ThinkPad with Win 8.1 64-bit and Win 8 32-bit. Couldn't find 2 drivers and this found them and it works.
Only one disadvantage - You will be prompted to sign in to download drivers (can be uncomfortable for somebody :)

Comment: I prefer not to use addition software or utilities if it can be avoided!